# Do you know as soon as you are riding on a flat?

Tags: puncture, damage

Today I did a 55km ride and at some point I got a puncture on my rear tyre. The problem is that I do not know if I kept on driving for a while on it and damaged the tyre or the rim, although the rim does not look damaged when I look at it from the outside. For some reason, which might be because I thought that I was pedalling more than I should, I looked at the tyre and saw that I got a flat, which at such point, stopped immediately. This is my first puncture and I am going to my bike shop to repair it this time around, and then buy a repair kit, since today I was lucky that I stopped at a common place from where they could pick my up, and I am not going to risk getting stranded in the middle of nowhere some time in the future.

My question is, if you do not look at the tyre and you get a flat, do you realise that you have a flat? Or you may end up driving for some kilometres before you take notice? Especially if you are tired after a long ride?

Comment: I think it depends on the person and terrain. On the road I generally notice quite quickly, but on snow, less so. Also, front vs rear is different in feel

Comment: Generally two things:  1) The bike feels "sluggish".  2) The bike is riding amazingly smoothly for a few minutes, then the ride suddenly gets quite harsh. You may also notice poor handling on turns, or even experience a "spin out" on a turn, where the tire slides unexpectedly.

Comment: With normal rims and tires, in good condition, you'd have to ride for an hour or more on a totally flat tire to damage the rim.  The tire can be damaged much sooner -- perhaps in 10-20 minutes -- if ridden completely flat, especially on rough pavement.  And tubeless tires would likely be damaged sooner than tube style (though the tube might be wrecked fairly quickly).

Comment: Consider learning to replace a tube by yourself.  Its not hard, its just a bunch of techniques.  You need a tube, a pump, and probably a lever or two, plus any tool needed to undo your axle from the frame.

Comment: Opinion: you know as soon as it's flat enough to damage anything, if not sooner. Reasoning: running on the rims causes both the damage and the very worst of the handling, and the damage isn't instant, while the handling starts to suffer while there's still some air left. The possible exception is if you hit a pothole or other hard edge at just the wrong moment, while the tyre barely holds enough air to support normal riding.. Even then the most likely effect is probably a pinch flat to make patching more interesting.

Comment: This kind of contradicts the usual warning that flat tire means immediate personal injury or death.

Comment: @ojs - Where did anyone say that???

Comment: It shows up quite often anyone asks about riding stuff with puncture or blowout risk.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My question is, if you do not look at the tyre and you get a flat, do you realise that you have a flat?

Typically I can catch well before the rim starts bottoming out without looking. If the bike ever feels "off" I will give a quick check by it plopping my self down on the saddle.  If the tire is going down this will usually bottom out the rim which I know shouldn't be happening. At this point I start visually checking things.  If the bike feels a bit soft (I.e., we have lost some pressure but not enough to bottom out the rim) I will give it a quick visual by looking at the tire bulge when I bounce on the saddle.  Finally if the bike feels solid I know it's my imagination and continue riding.

> Or you may end up driving for some kilometres before you take notice? Especially if you are tired after a long ride?

After a while these checks become second nature and you start doing them without thinking even when tired.

Comment: Depends how quick the tyre is loosing air.  If its a slow leak, the bike might go fine for kilometres, but get progressively squirmier in the corners.   A fast leak and you're on the rims immediately (this is often accompanied by a PSSSSHHHTT!!! of air)    Somewhere in the middle, the plop on the saddle while riding technique shows if you can make the rims bottom out.

Comment: I find the hardest situation is when climbing.  A wheel can feel like it's going flat when it isn't, due to your pedalling pattern, and it's difficult to visually check the rear wheel.  Plus you don't want to stop to check it.